# Why does my nested POJO return null from a form in Play! 1.x

Tags: playframework-1.x

In Play! Framework 1.5.1, why am I getting null back for thingy.Owner ?  Shouldn't the automatic binding take care of this?

User class

```
    package models;

@Entity
@Table(name="objtest_user")
public class User extends Model
{
    @Required
    public String username;

    @Password
    @Required
    public String password;

    public String fullname;

    public User(String username, String password, String fullname)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.fullname;
    }
}
```

and this Thingy class that references the User class

```
    package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.jpa.*;
import play.data.validation.*;

@Entity
public class Thingy extends Model
{
    @Required
    public String Name;

    @ManyToOne
    public User Owner;

    public Thingy(String name, User owner)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Owner = owner;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

and this Template form

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title:'Home' /}

<p>Current user = ${currentUser}</p>


#{form @saveThingy(), id:'saveThingy'}
    <input type="text" id="thingy.Name" name="thingy.Name"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="thingy.Owner" name="thingy.Owner" value="${currentUser}"/>
    <input type="submit" id="Save" value="Save"/>
#{/form}
```

Controller method

```
public static void saveThingy(Thingy thingy)
{
    System.out.println("Name = " + thingy.Name);
    System.out.println("Owner = " + thingy.Owner);

    thingy.save();
}
```

Comment: Oh, and currentUser is correctly populated, based on my test render on the form.  Code to set that is public static void index()
    {
     User currentUser = User.findById(1L);
     System.out.println("Current user from controller " + currentUser);
     renderArgs.put("currentUser", currentUser);
        render();
    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the following line

```
<input type="hidden" id="thingy.Owner" name="thingy.Owner" value="${currentUser}"/>
```

To

```
<input type="hidden" id="thingy.Owner" name="thingy.Owner.id" value="${currentUser.id}"/>
```

If you check out the docs (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.x/controllers#params), and look for JPA object binding section, it talks about requiring sub objects to have an id. Play when it finds an ID for an object, it will load the relavent entity via JPA/Hibernate.

Comment: Yup, that works - massive thanks.  Pretty much every Play! question I've ever asked has been resolved by you. Legend.